# Setting time for a particular action to be happened-LibGdx

Tags: libgdx

In my LibGdx game,enemies are coming in to the screen one by one.

I want to make enemeies appear at a particular time after the game starts.

How can I do it efficiently?

Comment: You can use Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() to modify your own custom timer(s) for releasing waves of enemies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll do it this way

In your game class

```
float time = 0; // This will contain the time
```

In your game loop

```
time += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(); // This will add to your time variable the time between two frames
```

And something like this when you want to do something

```
if (time > 5) // If 5s happened
{
    // Make ennemy appear
}
```

This would do the trick ! Simply put time to 0 again to restart the timer.

```
time -= 5; // Restart the timer by substract of elapsed time
```

Comment: _"Simply put time to 0 again to restart the timer."_ You should add that to the code :)

Comment: In fact, you should set time to `time -= 5;`. The way it is now, you'll get, on average, _less than_ one enemy per 5 seconds as you'll 'lose' a few ms every time. By reducing the time by 5 seconds, you keep these few ms for the next enemy :)

Comment: That's true, as @AminePaleo said below :)

Answer (score 2):

you could use delta time

for example :

```
private final static float TIME_OUT = 5;
private float time = 0;


private update(){
     time += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
     if (time > TIME_OUT){
          attack();
          time -= TIME_OUT; // or set to 0 to repeat the process
     }
}
```

Comment: so it should not be "final"?

Comment: oh, ok, that's true